# Looking for a formal proof for a statement

Tags: integration

I'm going over Spivak's Calculus and I'm reading the proof that $\int_{a}^{b} f+g = \int_{a}^{b}f+\int_{a}^{b}g$, but I'm getting stuck on this part:

Let $L(f,P)$ be the lower sum of $f$ with partition $P$, $U(f,P)$ be the upper sum of $f$ with partition $P$. We can derive the following statements:

(1) $L(f,P) + L(g, P) \leq L(f+g,P) \leq \int_{a}^{b}f+\int_{a}^{b}g \leq U(f+g,P) \leq U(f,P) + U(g, P)$.

(2) $L(f,P) + L(g, P) \leq  \int_{a}^{b}f+\int_{a}^{b}g \leq U(f,P) + U(g, P)$.

Since $U(f,P) - L(f,P)$ and $U(g,P) - L(g,P)$ can both made as small as desired, it follows that

$U(f,P) + U(g,P) - L(f,P) - L(g,P)$  can also be made as small as possible. Then

$\int_{a}^{b}f+g = \int_{a}^{b}f+\int_{a}^{b}g$

I don't quite get the last part. I understand that as we make $U(f,P) + U(g,P) - L(f,P) - L(g,P)$ arbitrarily small, we can reduce the gap to virtually 0. However, I can't seem to produce a formal proof to convince myself. Can someone please provide a formal proof to help me understand it better?

Comment: The title of your question seems different from what you write in the content.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @D_S updated both the title and content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = \int_a^b f, B = \int_a^bg$, and $C = \int_a^bf+g$.  You want to show that $A + B = C$.

Let $s_P = U(f,P)+ U(g,P)$ and $t_P = L(f,P) + L(g,P)$.

In the proof, it is explained that the nonnegative number $s_P - t_P$ can be made "as small as possible," meaning given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a partition $P$ such that $s_P - t_P < \epsilon$.  It is also explained that

$$t_P \leq A + B \leq s_P$$

$$t_P \leq C \leq s_P$$

Suppose that $A+B$ is not equal to $C$, say $A+ B > C$.  Let $\epsilon = (A+B) -C > 0$.  Then there exists a partition $P$ such that $s_P - t_P < (A+B)-C$.

This is impossible: if you have four numbers $\alpha \leq \beta < \gamma \leq \delta$, then of course $\delta - \alpha$ is greater than or equal to $\gamma - \beta$.